# React update a property in setInterval works twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setinterval

In short: why in setInterval, updating a variable that should be updated once, it updates twice?

```
compTurn() {
      let intervalId = setInterval(()=> {
        if (this.flash==this.round) {
          clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
        if (this.seq[this.flash]==1){
          this.greenFlash();
        }
        if (this.seq[this.flash]==2){
          this.yellowFlash();
        }
        if (this.seq[this.flash]==3){
          this.blueFlash();
        }
        if (this.seq[this.flash]==4){
          this.redFlash();
        }
        this.flash++;
      }
      , 1500);  
    }
```

My first small game app contains buttons that changes their colours in some conditions according to a given sequence. this happens in compTurn method. everytime a colour is changed, the flash counter increases.
The game starts with round=1 and should grow as the player is 'ok'. (code is not full at the moment)
In round 1 for e.g, one button flashes (changes colour) and then flash grows, and then the interval should end.

But in setInterval, in compTurn, the flash updates twice (in round 1, the flash turns 2).

Would like some help.

Edited:  also, when the session is done, when I'm pressing the start button again - nothing happens (the on press doesn't starts play() again. How can I make this happen?
(I want the user to restart the game with pressing the start again).

full code that I'm working on right now is here:

```
export default class App extends Component{ 
  constructor (props){
    super(props);
    this.flash=0
    this.round=1
    this.seq=[1,2,3,1,4] //will be random, this is just for testing
    this.playerSeq=[] 
    this.win=false
    this.ok=true
    this.score=0
    this.state = {
      renderView: false,
      greenB: {
        backgroundColor: 'darkgreen'
      },
      yellowB: {
        backgroundColor: 'orange'
      },
      blueB: {
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
      },
      redB: {
        backgroundColor: 'red'
      }
    }
    this.play=this.play.bind(this)
    this.greenFlash=this.greenFlash.bind(this)
    this.blueFlash=this.blueFlash.bind(this)
    this.redFlash=this.redFlash.bind(this)
  }

  play(){
    for (var i=0;i<this.round;i++){
      this.compTurn();
      //this.playerTurn();
    }
  }

  playerTurn(){
    //
  }
  compTurn() {
      let intervalId = setInterval(()=> {
        if (this.flash==this.round) {
          clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
        if (this.seq[this.flash]==1){
          this.greenFlash();
        }
        if (this.seq[this.flash]==2){
          this.yellowFlash();
        }
        if (this.seq[this.flash]==3){
          this.blueFlash();
        }
        if (this.seq[this.flash]==4){
          this.redFlash();
        }
        this.flash++;
      }
      , 1500);  
    }

  greenFlash(){
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState( {
            greenB:{
              ...this.state.style1, backgroundColor: 'lightgreen'
            }
            })
        }, 200);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState( {
            greenB:{
              ...this.state.style1, backgroundColor: 'darkgreen'
            }
            })
        }, 1000);
    } 

  yellowFlash(){
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState( {
          yellowB:{
            ...this.state.style1, backgroundColor: 'yellow'
          }
          })
      }, 200);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState( {
          yellowB:{
            ...this.state.style1, backgroundColor: 'orange'
          }
          })
        }, 1000);
   }

  blueFlash(){
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState( {
          blueB:{
            ...this.state.style1, backgroundColor: 'lightblue'
          }
          })
      }, 200);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState( {
          blueB:{
            ...this.state.style1, backgroundColor: 'blue'
          }
          })
        }, 1000);
   }

  redFlash(){
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState( {
          redB:{
            ...this.state.style1, backgroundColor: 'pink'
          }
          })
      }, 200);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState( {
          redB:{
            ...this.state.style1, backgroundColor: 'red'
          }
          })
        }, 1000);
   }

  render(){
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.playB}
        onPress={this.play}> 
        <Text style={{
          color:'white',
          height: 30,
          width:60,
          }}>START</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.greenB, this.state.greenB]}></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.yellowB, this.state.yellowB]}></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.blueB, this.state.blueB]}></TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.redB, this.state.redB]}></TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  greenB:{
    padding: 5,
    height: 80,
    width: 80,  
    borderRadius:160,    
  },
  yellowB:{
    padding: 5,
    height: 80,
    width: 80,  
    borderRadius:160,    
  },
  blueB:{
    padding: 5,
    height: 80,
    width: 80,  
    borderRadius:160,    
  },
  redB:{
    padding: 5,
    height: 80,
    width: 80,  
    borderRadius:160,    
  },
  playB:{
    alignSelf: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  }

});
```

Comment: `play` doesn't reinitialize values

Comment: the constructor does, isn't that ok?

Comment: constructor is recalled????

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I thought you were talking about the initial reload. I reset the properties in play() and it did restart the game, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial flash value is 0, so the function is called when the flash value is 0 and 1. That's the problem. If you want flash value to be 1, you should return after `clearInterval(intervalId);`

In case of `this.flash` is 1, it clearInterval and run the following script and it, so it becomes 2.

````
compTurn() {
      let intervalId = setInterval(()=> {
        if (this.flash==this.round) {
          clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
        if (this.seq[this.flash]==1){
          this.greenFlash();
        }
        if (this.seq[this.flash]==2){
          this.yellowFlash();
        }
        if (this.seq[this.flash]==3){
          this.blueFlash();
        }
        if (this.seq[this.flash]==4){
          this.redFlash();
        }
        this.flash++;
      }
      , 1500);  
    }
    ```
````

Comment: I think I thought clearInterval is like a "break", I didn't think it will run the interval anyway